# Magento customer login redirect issues

Tags: php, magento, redirect, authentication

Here is an issue on customer login, when I try to login, whatever it's successful or failed, the page always redirect to the Category Page, When I changed the setting to "No" of the "Login Option" in backend (Stay on the current page).

After redirection, I clicked into the login/dashboard page again, the error/welcome message was displayed there. And sometimes, the error message will be displayed on homepage.

So which file should I check? any suggestion to resolve?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check following steps to resolve issue :

1)Please check your customer Account controller method loginPost()

2)Check have you installed magento module that override account controller if yes then disable that module and check it.

3)"customer_login" observer event in magento if you found this event in any module then just disable that module and check it. From this event observer it is possible to redirect to other page.